# Mongoose multi update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update multiple docs with different values.

My Database looks something like this.

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "value": 50
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "value": 100
    }
]
```

This Query return an error because i'm passing an array instead of an object in the $set.

```
    Model.update({_id: {$in: ids}}, {$set: ids.value}, {multi: true};
```

I want my database to look like this

```
[
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "value": 4
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "value": 27
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all your `update()` query is not ok..

See documentation for this [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)

> `Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);`

Suppose your current db model contains docs like this (as you described in question as well):

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "value": 50
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "value": 100
   }
];
```

and you've below array which contains objects (i.e., docs) to be modified with current db's docs to like this:

```
idsArray: [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "value": 4
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "value": 27
    }
];
```

From my experience with mongodb & mongoose, i don't think you can update all docs with single line query (that's you're trying to do).. (P.S. I don't know about that so I am not sure to this..)

But to make your code work, you will be doing something like this:

Idea: Loop over each doc in docs i.e, `idsArray` and call update() over it..

So, Here's code to this:

```
idsArray.forEach(function(obj) {
    Model.update({_id: obj._id}, {$set: {value: obj.value}});
});
```

In above code, I am supposing you've `_id` values in db docs as they 're written above (i.e, `"_id": 1`).. But if they're like this `"_id": ObjectId('1')`

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId('1'),
    "value": 50
  },
  .....
  .....
]
```

then you'll be need to convert `_id` to `ObjectId(obj._id)` in update() query.. 
so for that you'll be doing like this.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

idsArray.forEach(function(obj) {
   Model.update({_id: ObjectId(obj._id)}, {$set: {value: obj.value}});
});
```

P.S. Just confirm it (i.e., `_id`) before go forward..

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Comment: I tried earlier something similar where I loop thru my values. My question if I take that method where do I set my res.end(); because if I set my res.end() after the foreach finish I still have a bunch of callbacks waiting for my Model.update to finish.

Comment: via callback (i guess) - try to make a func `function(callback) {callback();}` which updates all docs in db and return callback into main function where you'll do your that work; just try this way.

Comment: a function (say it: `callbackFunc`) which will do update all your docs and then return callback to from where it was called (suppose: `mainFunc`), so it means when your all docs will be updated (means callbackFunc finishes) then you 'll do/call `res.end()`

Answer (score 11):

Supposing you had an array of objects that you wanted to update in your collection on matching ids like

```
var soldItems = [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "value": 4
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "value": 27
        }
    ];
```

then you could use the **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method on the array to iterate it and update your collection:

```
soldItems.forEach(function(item)){
    Model.update({"_id": item._id}, {"$set": {"value": item.value }}, callback);
});
```

or use promises as

```
var updates = [];
soldItems.forEach(function(item)){
    var updatePromise = Model.update({"_id": item._id}, {"$set": {"value": item.value }});
    updates.push(updatePromise);
});

Promise.all(updates).then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

or using **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```
var updates = soldItems.map(function(item)){
    return Model.update({"_id": item._id}, {"$set": {"value": item.value }});       
});

Promise.all(updates).then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

---

For larger arrays, you could take advantage of using a bulk write API for better performance. For Mongoose versions `>=4.3.0` which support `MongoDB Server 3.2.x`, 
you can use **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** for updates. The following example shows how you can go about this:

```
var bulkUpdateCallback = function(err, r){
    console.log(r.matchedCount);
    console.log(r.modifiedCount);
}
// Initialise the bulk operations array
var bulkOps = soldItems.map(function (item) { 
    return { 
        "updateOne": { 
            "filter": { "_id": item._id } ,              
            "update": { "$set": { "value": item.value } } 
        }         
    }    
});

// Get the underlying collection via the native node.js driver collection object
Model.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps, { "ordered": true, w: 1 }, bulkUpdateCallback);
```

For Mongoose versions `~3.8.8, ~3.8.22, 4.x` which support MongoDB Server `>=2.6.x`, you could use the **[`Bulk API`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** as follows

```
var bulk = Model.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

soldItems.forEach(function(item) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": item._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "value": item.value }
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(function(err, r) {
           // do something with the result
           bulk = Model.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
           counter = 0;
        });
    }
});

// Catch any docs in the queue under or over the 500's
if (counter > 0) {
    bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
       // do something with the result here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Multi update can be used only for updating multiple documents to the same value(s) or updating with the same [update operation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) for all documents.

If you want to update to different values you have to use several update statements.