# Update database with multiple reference database issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am fairly new to mongoose/express. What I am struggling with is trying to update new data from html form and save it to database that has references. I have a business model with location reference to location model. Here's the codes.

edit.ejs

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
        <form action="/<%= bus._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
            <!-- business info -->
            <h3>Business Information</h3>
            <input class="form-input" type="input" name="bus[logo]" value="<%= bus.logo %>">
            <input class="form-input" type="input" name="bus[name]" value="<%= bus.name %>">
            <% bus.location.forEach(function(location) { %>
            <input class="form-input" type="input" name="bus.location[street]" value="<%= location.street %>">
            <input class="form-input" type="input" name="bus.location[city]" value="<%= location.city %>">
            <div class="state-input">
                <select class="form-inline" name="bus.location[state]">
                    <option value="" disabled selected><%= location.state %></option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    ...
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>   
            </div><!--State-input -->
            <input class="form-inline" type="input" name="bus.location[zipcode]" value="<%= location.zipcode %>">
            <% }) %>
            <!--Contact info-->
            <h4>Contact Information</h4>
            <% bus.contact.forEach(function(contact) { %>
            <input class="form-input" type="url" name="bus[url]" value="<%= bus.url %>">
            <input class="form-input" type="email" name="bus.contact[email]" value="<%= contact.email %>">
            <input class="form-input" type="tel" name="bus.contact[phone]" value="<%= contact.phone %>">
            <input class="form-input" type="input" name="bus.contact[twitter]" value= "<%= contact.twitter %>">
            <input class="form-input" type="input" name="bus.contact[facebook]" value="<%= contact.facebook %>">
            <input class="form-input" type="input" name="bus.contact[instagram]" value="<%= contact.instagram %>">
            <% }) %>
```

index.js - edit routes

```
//(edit.ejs) Edit Route 
app.get('/:id/edit', function(req, res) {
    Business.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('location')
    .populate('contact')
    .populate('images')
    .exec(function(err, bus) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('edit', {bus:bus});
        }
    });
});
app.put('/:id', function(req, res) {
    Business.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.bus, function(err, bus) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/' + req.params.id + '/edit');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/' + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

The business (bus) updates nicely but bus.location doesn't update.
Business model

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
var busSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String,
    logo: String,
    desc: String,
    subs: Number,
    video: String,
    url: String,
    firstRun: Boolean,
    location:[ 
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Location'
      }
    ],
    contact:[
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Contact'
      }
    ],
    images:[
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Image'
      }
    ],
    comments:[
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Comment'
      }   
    ],
    created: {
       type: Date, default: Date.now
    }
});
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
module.exports = mongoose.model('Business', busSchema);
```

Location Model

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
var locSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zipcode: Number
    }  
);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', locSchema);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the error? How is the data flow? Can you explain your code? Always be specific and make your best effort before asking, and don't treat Stack Overflow as a repository of tutorials. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Business`, `Location` and `Contact` are different collections.

`findByIdAndUpdate` only updates one collection, which yours in particular is `Business`. In order to update the other collections, you need to perform operations on those collections.

If you are trying to update "existing" locations and contacts, then you'll need to provide also their IDs. Also, you have an "array" of locations and contacts, so you need additional `[]` to your names.

```
<% bus.location.forEach(function(location, i) { %>
    <input type="hidden" name="location[<?= i ?>][id]" value="<%= location.id %>">
    <input class="form-input" type="input" name="location[<?= i ?>][street]" value="<%= location.street %>">
    <!-- etc -->
<% }) %>

<% bus.contact.forEach(function(contact, i) { %>
    <input type="hidden" name="contact[<?= i ?>][id]" value="<%= contact.id %>">
    <input class="form-input" type="email" name="contact[<?= i ?>][email]" value="<%= contact.email %>">
    <!-- etc -->
<% }) %>
```

From my (and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210535/1022914)) experience, I do not think it is possible to update multiple documents at once. This means, in your route handler, you will need to iterate over each item in the arrays that you are given and update them one by one. The answer in the other post though is not quite right IMO as you shouldn't be using synchronous `forEach` to do asynchronous mongoose operations as it will lead to unexpected behaviour.

You have three main tasks to do: update the business, update their existing locations, and update their existing contacts.

I like to use [async.js](http://caolan.github.io/async/) to perform multiple asynchronous operations. In your particular case, I would use [async.series](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) to do each task and [async.eachSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOfSeries) to do an operation on each element of your arrays.

**Warning** This is untested but it would look something like this:

```
app.put('/:id', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.bus);
    console.log(req.body.location); // should be an array of objects
    console.log(req.body.contact); // should be an array of objects

    // perform each task one by one
    async.series([
        function updateBusiness (done) {
            // you need to always call the callback i.e. done to indicate the task is "done"
            // - if you pass an error as an argument, it means the task failed and stop everything
            // - otherwise, move onto the next task

            /*Business.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.bus, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err); // task failed and stop everything
                }
                done(); // task went well and proceed to the next task
            });*/

            // simplified
            Business.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.bus, done);
        },
        function updateLocations (done) {
            // find and update each location
            async.eachSeries(req.body.location || [], function (location, done2) {
                Location.findByIdAndUpdate(location.id, location, done2);
            }, done);
        },
        function updateContacts (done) {
            // find and update each contact
            async.eachSeries(req.body.contact || [], function (contact, done2) {
                Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(contact.id, contact, done2);
            }, done);
        }
    ], function allDone (err) {
        // a task failed somewhere
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/' + req.params.id + '/edit');
        // all tasks were completed
        } else {
            res.redirect('/' + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

If there is an error, look at the console logs.

Comment: I was able to figure what went wrong with my code structure when you advised to add  other [] an id's for contact and location. I am not familiar with async.js tool but intend to look into that. Thank you!

Comment: Curious: with your change, did it actually save using just the `Business.findByIdAndUpdate` ? Or did you have to do more?

Comment: Yes I was able to save using Business.findByIdAndUpdate then redirect at the end of code. As for contact and location, I had to use findByIdAndUpdate for contact and location individually with forEach. Takes up several more lines but intend to figure how to best refactor them. As I said before, fairly new to this and still learning the craft. But, I was able to get it to work with your help!